# Eureka-client trying to register to random serviceUrl of eureka server

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-config

using 'Dalston.BUILD-SNAPSHOT' for spring-cloud-dependencies, with spring boot '1.5.2.RELEASE'.

In my current setup, I have

eureka server
config server (running on random ports)

Eureka server on localhost is running with below configuration.

```
server:
  port: 8761

spring:
  application:
    name: EUREKA
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: false

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: peer1
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
  server:
    waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
```

And the Config-server as eureka client with below configuration

```
eureka:
  instance:
    instanceId: ${spring.cloud.client.hostname}:${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.uuid}}
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/,http://localhost:8762/eureka/
```

As per the documentation my understanding is, eureka client try to register with first serviceUrl(http://localhost:8761/eureka/) and if its not available will try with the other serviceUrl. And was happening as expected till some time back.

---

However today i observed, eureka client is first trying to register with "http://localhost:8762/eureka/" and as the eureka server on 8762 is not running causing below error

```
2017-04-04 02:06:31.423 DEBUG 4558 --- [nfoReplicator-0] n.d.s.t.j.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient : Jersey HTTP POST http://localhost:8762/eureka//apps/CONFIGSERVER with instance 192.168.1.2:CONFIGSERVER:d2b5e5fa-a0e2-48a5-98c9-53fd362dd3d7; statusCode=N/A
2017-04-04 02:06:31.425 ERROR 4558 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error

com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:570) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.register(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:118) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:79) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:119) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:798) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:104) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator$1.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:88) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_66]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

However if i change the order of serviceUrl to

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8762/eureka/,http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

Eureka client is registered on 8761, without any errors.

I could see below code from "com.netflix.discovery.shared.resolver.aws.ZoneAffinityClusterResolver" that it randomize the serviceUrl for registering the client.

```
  public List<AwsEndpoint> getClusterEndpoints() {
        List[] parts = ResolverUtils.splitByZone(this.delegate.getClusterEndpoints(), this.myZone);
        List myZoneEndpoints = parts[0];
        List remainingEndpoints = parts[1];
        List randomizedList = randomizeAndMerge(myZoneEndpoints, remainingEndpoints);
        if(!this.zoneAffinity) {
            Collections.reverse(randomizedList);
        }

        if(logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Local zone={}; resolved to: {}", this.myZone, randomizedList);
        }

        return randomizedList;
    }
```

Please suggest if i understand it incorrectly or any recent changes to the way eureka clients are registered.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this hasn't changed in a very long time.

Comment: That class hasn't changed, but others that consume `ClusterResolver` had. So it's likely this is used now when I wasn't before.

Comment: Does it happen with Camden.SR6?

Comment: @spencergibb, I could see the same error with 'Camden.SR6'. Any pointers. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have any pointers.